# How to increase the size of the busy cursor in flex mobile

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5, busy-cursor

I tried using the default busy cursor in flex 4.6 mobile. But the busy cursor is very small compared to the one available in web application. Is it possible to increase he size of the cursor. I dont want to add image instead of cursor.Any ideas??

Or atleast is it possible to use the busy indicator component instead of the normal busu cursor?

Answer (score 2):

Generally I stay away from the busy cursor for several reasons, including the fact that it is so small on mobile apps. The busy indicator is very easy to use and can be positioned and sized how you like:

```
<s:BusyIndicator id="myBusyIndicator" width="100" height="100" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" visible="false"/>
```

Then, when you want to show it, set the visible property to true.  For instance, if you are using a httpService you could do the below:

```
private function myResultHandler(e:ResultEvent):void
{
    myBusyIndicator.visible = false;
    //handle data results
}

private function myFaultHandler(e:FaultEvent):void
{
    myBusyIndicator.visible = false;
    //handle fault results
}

<s:HTTPService id="myHttpService" result="myResultHandler(event)" fault="myFaultHandler(event)" invoke="myBusyIndicator.visible = true"/>
```